# Loading UTF keymap file

Tags: key-bindings, macos

I need to load a particular keymap file that enables me to write underscore, special characters by typing

```
:set keymap=iast
```

where `iast.vim` is my keymap file

This no longer works. Where should this file reside.

I use the mac and my vim package is updated by homebrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs (`:help mbyte-keymap`):

> The value of the 'keymap' option specifies a keymap file to use.  The name of
>   this file is one of these two:
>
> ```
> keymap/{keymap}_{encoding}.vim
> keymap/{keymap}.vim
> ```

I would expect `$HOME/.vim/keymap/iast.vim`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. In the past on my linux machines, I used to place the iast.vim in the system directories (somewhere inside /usr/local) where vim was installed.

Comment: Theoretically you ought to be able to place it anywhere on the runtime path, but users tend to prefer `~/.vim` for custom stuff.